# Doctrine2: entity visibility in multi processes

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, doctrine-query

Here is an example.php on the Web:

```
...
$page = new SomeEntity();
$page->setName("xx");  // name is primary key
$em->persist($page);
....
```

Question: what would happen, when example2.php asks:

```
$result = $em->find('SomeEntity', 'xx');
```

? null or object $page?

I'm assuming example.php is still running and didn't call $em->flush() yet.

Edit:

Maybe it's also decisive how I call $em:

```
$em = \Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('doctrine');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until no flush operation has been performed, data is not persisted. Therefore, data is not shared with other processes.

Your `$result` variable will be `null`.